# The best way to get a page of threads + stickies?

Tags: mysql

Using mysql its pretty easy to get a page (lets say 20) of threads. However i'd like to push up stickies. Whats the best way to do this? One way i thought was to use two queries, the first getting the sticky (if on first page) the next a regular query excluding stickies. But i still need to substract the amount of stickies so it seems like i need to make two queries each time.

I could also write one which may be better but it may need a subquery which is bad? i am actually not sure how to write this

I'm sure there is a pretty good way but i dont know much about mysql so what do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to modify your WHERE clause and order by accordingly:

```
SELECT 
    fields
FROM 
    threads 
WHERE 
    forum_id = X 
    and 
    (
        sticky = 1 
        OR (other conditions if needed)
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    sticky, something, somethingElse 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

This will actually work on pages other than the first page because of the ordering.